# CdkDragDrop Drop not working with "ng build --prod" configuration

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop, angular-dragdrop, dragdropmodule

I am using cdkDropList of Angular material CdkDragDrop. Drag is working but drop is not working.
It is only happening when I am using "ng build --prod". I tried with removing all default configuration for production in angular.json file.

Here is what I am facing -

[image: issue]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Any errors of any kind?

Comment: No errors. It is happening because I am using drag and drop inside a dialog.